# $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\beta_n = 1$, if $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \beta_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

So it is known that for a sequence $(\beta_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \beta_n$ converges to $a \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$ if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^n \beta_k = a$. If this product does not converage to any $a \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$, we say it diverges.

I want to prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\beta_n = 1$, if $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \beta_n$ converges.

I know this is true, as any other value would continue to change the product other than $0$, which was disallowed '$a \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$'.

Not sure how to go about proving this though, and ideas?

Comment: Take the log of the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

$$\beta_k = \frac{\prod_{m=1}^k\beta_m}{\prod_{m=1}^{k-1}\beta_m}$$

EDIT: The denominator isn't zero since none of the terms in the product can be zero (since it doesn't converge to $0$). You know the product converges to $a$. Same is true for the product with one index off. What do you know about limit of a quotient if both enumerator and denominator have an existing limit?